# Would like to get last signin for guest account in azure AD for last 30 days

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have a very specific question in regards Signin options in Azure active directory . I see that within signin options you get all the details about users who have logged in . i want to get details only about guest users who have logged in last 30 days and their last signin .

How can i get that ? is their any powershell script that i can execute

i found this blog https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/azure-active-directory-automating-guest-user-management/

#Get all the Guest Users
$guestusers=Get-AzureADUser -Filter "UserType eq 'Guest' and AccountEnabled eq true"
$guestusers.displayname

I am not sure as to how should we proceed from below and how can i get the displayname for the users who logged in last 30 days .

Can somebody help me with the below commands that i need to execute ?

## For each Guest user, validate there is a login in the last week

foreach ($guestUser in $guestUsers) {
Write-Output "Getting User's logins for the last week"
$guestUserSignIns = Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs -Filter "UserID eq '$($guestUser.ObjectID)' and createdDateTime ge $queryStartDateTimeFilter"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Try this :

```
$guestuserIDs= (Get-AzureADUser -Filter "UserType eq 'Guest' and AccountEnabled eq true" | Select-Object ObjectId).ObjectId

$startTime = (get-date).AddDays(-30).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

foreach($guestUserID in $guestuserIDs){
    Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs -Filter "createdDateTime gt $startTime and UserId eq '$guestUserID'" |Select-Object UserId,UserDisplayName,CreatedDateTime 
}
```

It displays the sign-in record timestamp, username, user ID of guest users:

[image]

Let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: Hi , @KumarKaushal Glad to know that my solution is helpful. Please click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in to accept it as an answer, so that it will help others and close this query : )